# function testSuiteWillStart under XCTestObservation is getting called when running tests from Xcode

Tags: xctest, xcuitest, xctestcase, xcode9.4

I am using Xcode version - Version 9.4.1 (9F2000).

I am trying to create custom logs for tests running with XCUITest by overwriting XCTestObservation class and registering it with test class.

Observer class: TestObserver

```
class TestObserver : NSObject, XCTestObservation {

    public func testSuiteWillStart(_ testSuite: XCTestSuite) {
      print("I am inside function testSuiteWillStart --> \(testSuite)")
} }
```

Setup in my test case:

```
class MyTestCase: XCTestCase{

override class func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    XCTestObservationCenter.shared.addTestObserver(TestObserver())
}}
```

I tried running test using Xcode and Fastlane both but the function testSuiteWillStart is not getting called at all. Has anyone faced similar issue?

Answer (score 2):

The function `testSuiteWillStart` will be called only when the Test Observer is added,

You can add observer using following line of code:

```
XCTestObservationCenter.shared.addTestObserver(observer) //observer is instance of object that confirms to XCTestObservation
```

Steps to follow:

1. Create a class that confirms to `XCTestObservation` protocol
2. Add class name in test bundle `info.plist` for key `NSPrincipalClass`

**Step 1:**

```
class SOTestObserver: NSObject, XCTestObservation {


    override init() {
        super.init()
        XCTestObservationCenter.shared.addTestObserver(self)
    }

    func testBundleWillStart(_ testBundle: Bundle) {
        print("---## \(#function), URL: \(testBundle.bundleURL)")
    }
}
```

**Step 2:**

if your project name has space for example `My App` then add following in `info.plist`

```
<key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
<string>My_AppUITests.SOTestObserver</string>
```

if your project name does not have spaces then add following

```
<key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME).SOTestObserver</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your Observer calls in UITest info.plist. Info.plist, create a new key "Principal Class" and Give a value as TestTarget.
E.g. UITests.TestObserver

While your testobserver class should look like

```
class TestObserver: NSObject, XCTestObservation {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        XCTestObservationCenter.shared().addTestObserver(self)
    }
   func testBundleWillStart(_ testBundle: Bundle) {
    print ("start")
   }
}
```